# Strange redirect issue

Tags: magento-1, redirect

This is my code from my function from controller:

```
public function step3Action(){
     $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('returns/rma_new/step2', array('m'=>'-1'));
     $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
     $redirectUrl2 = Mage::getUrl('returns/rma_new/step2', array('m'=>'-2'));
     $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl2);
     $redirectUrl3 = Mage::getUrl('returns/rma_new/step2', array('m'=>'-3'));
     $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl3);
}
```

Why am I redirect always to `returns/rma_new/step2` with the **-3** parameter  ? 
instead of `returns/rma_new/step2` with the **-1** parameter 
I am confused. thx

Comment: You are passing $redirectUrl3 so it will return always -3.

Comment: how I redirect to my url with the -1 parameter? can you give me an example ? thx

Comment: Magento first read all code in action and after that it will redirect. in you case last one always last one will work.

Comment: You have put some condition for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I forgot the add the **return** type:

```
public function step3Action(){
     $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('returns/rma_new/step2', array('m'=>'-1'));
     $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
     return $this;
}
```

If I add the **return** after my first redirect, the rest of them are ignored.